# Showing alert message in logs while doing copy in Ant

Tags: ant

I have `fromfolder=xxx` it has `one.txt` and
`tofolder=yyy` same file is there `one.txt`

While performing copy operation by using ant if it found same name of file is present then it will show alert message like files already present `one.txt` in log and should not overwrite the file.

```
 <target name="copyPublicHtml" description="Copy Public_html to output directory" >
     <touch>
     <fileset dir="../html"/>
    </touch>

       <copy todir="../html" failonerror="on" verbose="on" overwrite="false"> 
            <fileset dir="../src">           
       </copy>
  </target>
```

Comment: And what's the problem? You have set overwrite to false. This will prevent an overwrite and the message will be printed to the screen.

Comment: @ user2022204 : and  set verbose to false.

Comment: yes its not overwriting but i am not able to see any message in output console.. each time m seeing this meassge..

copyPublicHtml:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 3 seconds

Comment: and my script code is working properly but in log m not able to see the any message for duplicate file...

Comment: @Jayan i set it false as verbose then on console its not printing any copy log

Comment: Never seen any message about `skip overwriting` during `copy`. Maybe there is no such feature.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor i need log message like "file already exist" while doing copy

Comment: Ah now I understand. You want a status message instead of a silent overwrite. The core "copy" task does not support this. You alternatives are an embedded script (for example groovy) or a custom "copy" task.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [groovy task](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task) to iterate thru the files:

```
  <target name="copyPublicHtml" depends="init" description="Copy Public_html to output directory">
    <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" classpathref="build.path"/>

    <fileset id="srcFiles" dir="src"/>

    <groovy>
      project.references.srcFiles.each {
        def src = new File(it.toString())
        def trg = new File("html", src.name)

        if (trg.exists()) {
          project.log "File already exists: ${trg}"
        }

        ant.copy(file:it, todir:"html", verbose:"true", overwrite:"false")
      }
    </groovy>
  </target>
```