# Ant task to chek duplicate file in destination directory

Tags: ant

I am copying list of files from source directory to destination directory, i need to check duplicate file name before copying..

Thanks..

Comment: what is the behavior you expect in case of dupplicate? stop the build with error? just skip the file copying?

Comment: Hi peter, hi want to log the error message in log like "file already present" and it should not overwrite and it will keep copying for other files...

Comment: btw, seem you already asked the same question, well, that is not nice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586610/showing-alert-message-in-logs-while-doing-copy-in-ant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wondering, would this be sufficient?

```
<copy todir="../new/dir" overwrite="false" verbose="true">
    <fileset dir="src_dir"/>
</copy>
```

As manual says ( http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html ):

> verbose - Log the files that are being copied.
>
> overwrite - Overwrite existing files even if the destination files are newer.

As this would be a low effort solution. Otherwise, I think you need to create your own ant task.

---

**UPDATE:**

OK, so I checked the sources of ant copy task, and I believe you can do the required by extending it in your subclass (new ant task). As I assume you're running multiple files copying instead of just one.

So you need to:

- well this is not a must, but I believe it would help you: **download source code of Ant** (version you're using), let's assume you use the latest one: http://ant.apache.org/srcdownload.cgi
- **create your own ant task**. For docs how to do it and use it, see: http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html (check example section)
- make sure your class **extends class**: `org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Copy`
- **override superclass method doFileOperations**, as it's javadoc says:

> Actually does the file (and possibly empty directory) copies. This is a good method for subclasses to override.
>   
>   Check the method contents in the sources you downloaded and **your implenentation could look similar to this**:

```
@Override
protected void doFileOperations() {
    if (fileCopyMap.size() > 0) {

    Enumeration e = fileCopyMap.keys();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
        String fromFile = (String) e.nextElement();
        String[] toFiles = (String[]) fileCopyMap.get(fromFile);

        for (int i = 0; i < toFiles.length; i++) {
            String toFile = toFiles[i];

            if (fromFile.equals(toFile)) {
                log("Skipping self-copy of " + fromFile, verbosity);
                continue;
            }

            if (new File(toFile).exists) {
                log ("Warning: dest file already exists");
            }
        }
    }
            ...

    super.doFileOperations();
}
```

Comment: i did the same but it working fine but for duplicate file its not showing any log message... and for creating my own ant task could you give me any hint

Comment: see my update, however I didn't test it, so maybe you should :) possibly some updates are necessary

Comment: this way is working out thnaks.. but i am modifying the java code and each time i need to give my changes with ANT jar is there any generic built in ANT way there i can solve my problem

Comment: @user2022204 Hey, you should not modify Ant's source code or rebuild Ant's jar file. You should write your own task, which extends `copy` task, and put this in your project. Maybe you can finally find a way to solve it with pure Ant xml, but that will be complex and un-readable.

Comment: @coolcfan yes same thing i am doing but each time i need to provide my implemented method with ANT..so i am finding another way..

Comment: @user2022204 If the pure Ant way looks complicated, I prefer writing my own Ant task to pack the logic in Java code. In an alternative way, maybe you can write a macrodef with `groovy` invoking Groovy codes, so that everything can be put in a single xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more complete implementation:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException;
import org.apache.tools.ant.Project;
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Copy;

public class CopyNonDuplicateTast extends Copy {

    public CopyNonDuplicateTast() {
        setOverwrite(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void setOverwrite(boolean overwrite) {
        super.setOverwrite(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFileOperations() {

        Set<String> allToFiles = new HashSet<String>();

        for (final Map.Entry<String, String[]> e : fileCopyMap.entrySet()) {
            final String fromFile = e.getKey();
            final String[] toFiles = e.getValue();

            for (int i = 0; i < toFiles.length; i++) {
                final String toFile = toFiles[i];

                if (fromFile.equals(toFile)) {
                    continue;
                }

                File destFile = new File(toFile);
                if ((destFile.exists() && destFile.isFile()) || allToFiles.contains(toFile)) {
                    String msg = "Destination file \"" + toFile + "\" exists";
                    IOException ex = new IOException(msg);
                    if (failonerror) {
                        throw new BuildException(msg, ex, getLocation());
                    }
                    log(msg, Project.MSG_ERR);
                }
                allToFiles.add(toFile);
            }
        }

        super.doFileOperations();
    }

}
```

With this implementation, two filesets inside same copy task can fail:

```
<copyNonDuplicate todir="${deployment.dir}/languageFiles">
    <fileset dir="../MyComponent1/src">
        <include name="**/*.properties" />
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="../MyComponent2/src">
        <include name="**/*.properties" />
    </fileset>
</copyNonDuplicate>
```