# Checking file exists in a particular directory using Ant

Tags: ant

I have file `abc.txt` and i need to check that file exists in suppose
`c:\test\abc.txt` location

If true then I need to print some message else I need to perform some operation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586610/showing-alert-message-in-logs-while-doing-copy-in-ant/14613872#14613872

Comment: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html#presentselect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best is to use ant `<available ../>` to fill a property and then either using *ant-contrib* `<if>` task or create separate targets that run depending on the property value.

Check this answer for details: [Ant task to run an Ant target only if a file exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520546/ant-task-to-run-an-ant-target-only-if-a-file-exists)

Comment: Tang thanks, but i need to check a file in particular directory how can i check file from one directory to another

Comment: see https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/available.html and its examples - `file` can hold a path, so you could use `c:\test\abc.txt`.